# How to extract manually annotated tweets using Twitter API?

Tags: twitter, text-classification, corpus, tagged-corpus

I'm using text classification to classify dialects. First I need a large manually annotated tweets, and I have read a research paper that says:

> We have collected tweets that were published during June 2015. Arabic
>   linguists manually annotated a small part of these tweets, so we got
>   51,589 tweets with correct dialectal labels. These tweets were
>   manually found in Twitter and annotated by the linguists.

So this researcher was able to extract those tweets, I wanted to contact him but their emails weren't valid. He says those tweets were published during June 2015. How can I extract those tweets?

Comment: Have you tried to look for these researchers on Twitter?

Comment: Tho passage you quote from the article returns no hits in Google. Perhaps you could [edit] your question to include a link to the original, so as not to introduce additional new problems of rediscoverability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to assume that the researcher did that in realtime during June 2015.

Today, the only way to do that would be to use the Full Archive Search API (a premium, paid offering from Twitter) to search for those Tweets. In terms of the annotations, those would have been part of their research; Twitter does not annotate Tweets with dialectal labels.

Comment: Aha, okay, so you're saying that they themselves have annotated the tweets right? They didn't find it annotated?

Answer (score 0):

as I know researchers didn't have permission to publish tweets that they collect with twitter APIs.